# get an error `Internal Server Error [500]` when try to parsing data with ajax post

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

so, i want to parsing data with ajax post. but when i do that, my response status always 500 (internal server error). i don't know if my request post reached the controller or not.

EDIT: now it give me 419 status in network

I have read the same problem on stackoverflow, but there are various ways to solve it. so I'm confused, maybe someone can help solve my problem.

my ajax script & droppable :

```
$("#tool").droppable({
        accept : ".itemProducts",
        drop:function(event, ui){   
            id = $(ui.draggable).attr("value");         
            $.ajax({
                method: 'POST',
                type : 'POST',              
                dataType : 'JSON',
                url: '{{ url("/deleteProductTool/$cari->id") }}',
                data: {
                    id_tool : id,
                    _token : '{{ csrf_field() }}',
                 },
                success: function(){
                    $.get('{{ url("/showTools/$cari->id") }}'), function(data, status){
                        $('#tool').html(data);
                    }                   
                },              
            });
    }
    });
```

my routes :

```
Route::post('/deleteProductTool/{id}','ProductController@deleteProductTool');
```

and controller :

```
public function deleteProductTool(Request $request, $id){
        if (Request::ajax()) {
                $product = Product::findOrFail($id);
                if (empty($product)) {
                    abort(404);
                }

                $tool = Tool::findOrFail($request->id_tool);
                if (empty($tool)) {
                    abort(404);
                }                
                $hapus = ProductTool::where([
                    ['product_id', $product->id],
                    ['tool_id', $tool->id],
                ])->delete();

                return $hapus;   
            }else{
                abort(404);
            }
    }
```

here's the thing :

1. so the idea is, when i drag the `#itemProducts0` and drop it to the `#tool`, it should be execute deleteProductTool function in the controller.
2. i don't have a form. i just have this :

```
<div class="bin" id="product">
    <div id="itemProducts0" value="1" class="itemProducts ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle">PIjat Pinggang</div>
</div>
```

3. EDIT: here's my network [image: before, it was 500, now 419]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put this before this line `$("#tool").droppable`

```
   $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': jQuery('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
```

and put this in your head

```
 <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{csrf_token()}}">
```

Comment: thanks, for the response. i have edited my problem

Comment: i have edited my answer

Comment: i have tried the solutin, but now it give me back to 500 status... what happen :(

Comment: that's good so click on it and get a look to right and see the response of your request

Comment: it give me a view `419|page expired`. i use `Request::ajax()` on the controller. so it can't called statically

Comment: thanks sir. somehow i figure it out !